# Issues with UpdateDoc in Firebase/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working in a realtime private chat in react. When I tried to look for a user in the search bar, It is supposed to update a collection in Firebase, but It stills in blank.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import {
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs,
  setDoc,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
  getDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./firebase.js";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
const Search = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false);

  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "users"),
      where("displayName", "==", username)
    );

    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setUser(doc.data());
      });
    } catch (err) {
      setErr(true);
    }
  };

  const handleKey = (e) => {
    e.code === "Enter" && handleSearch();
  };

  const handleSelect = async () => {
    //check whether the group(chats in firestore) exists, if not create
    const combinedId =
      currentUser.uid > user.uid
        ? currentUser.uid + user.uid
        : user.uid + currentUser.uid;
    try {
      const res = await getDoc(doc(db, "chats", combinedId));

      if (!res.exists()) {
        //create a chat in chats collection
        await setDoc(doc(db, "chats", combinedId), { messages: [] });

        //create user chats
        await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid), {
          [combinedId + ".userInfo"]: {
            uid: user.uid,
            displayName: user.displayName,
      
          },
          [combinedId + ".date"]: serverTimestamp(),
        
        });
        console.log(user.displayName);
        await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", user.uid), {
          [combinedId + ".userInfo"]: {
            uid: currentUser.uid,
            displayName: currentUser.displayName,
          },
          [combinedId + ".date"]: serverTimestamp(),
        });
       
      }
    } catch (err) {}

    setUser(null);
    setUsername("")
  };
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <div className="searchForm">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Find a user"
          onKeyDown={handleKey}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          value={username}
        />
      </div>
      {err && <span>User not found!</span>}
      {user && (
        <div className="userChat" onClick={handleSelect}>
          <img src={user.photoURL} alt="" />
          <div className="userChatInfo">
            <span>{user.displayName}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

I changed the rules in firebase firestore, but the collection stills in blank.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhpUk.png)

Here the database Rules.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read,write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Here the Userchat sample structure:

 userChats Collection:
  Document 1 (currentUser.uid):
    - Chat1 (ID): 
      - userInfo:
        - uid: (ID of the other user)
        - displayName: (Name of the other user)
      - date: (Date of the last message)
    - Chat2 (ID):
      - userInfo:
        - uid: (ID of the other user)
        - displayName: (Name of the other user)
      - date: (Date of the last message)

  Document 2 (another user.uid):
    - Chat1 (ID): 
      - userInfo:
        - uid: (ID of the currentUser)
        - displayName: (Name of the currentUser)
      - date: (Date of the last message)
    - Chat3 (ID):
      - userInfo:
        - uid: (ID of the other user)
        - displayName: (Name of the other user)
      - date: (Date of the last message)
```

Comment: Add the sample structure of `userChats`

Comment: I posted in the answers section.

Comment: please delete the answer and copy it  then edit your question

Comment: It might be the problem in chat id

Comment: How I could Fix it?